# Search View sem precisar clicar enter para aparecer o resultado

Tags: android, listview, algoritmo-de-busca

fiz um `search` em minha lista porém ele necessita que eu clique em enter para concluir a busca e mostrar os resultados. Gostaria que o resultado viesse automaticamente ao digitar. Agradeço.

Meu código:

```
........ 

public class ListClientes extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
ListView lista;
ArrayList<Cliente> clientes;
EditText search;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_clientes);

    lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    search = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search);

    lista.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
    lista.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    atualizar(null);

    search.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            atualizar(null);
            return false;
        }
    });
}


public void atualizar(View view) {
    ClienteDao cliDao = new ClienteDao();

    clientes = cliDao.getListagem(" where nome like '" + search.getText().toString() + "%'");
    lista.setAdapter(new ClienteAdapter(getBaseContext(), clientes));

  } 

  ........
```

Comment: talvez não funcione porque celulares não tem botões, tente usar o evento `touch`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize o método  [addTextChangedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) do EditText ao invés do setOnKeyListener, como no exemplo:

```
search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        atualizar(null);
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
});
```